# How to put image to the right side of an ion-label?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I want to put a colored whats-app image on the right side of an ion-label and I can't figure it out how.
Here's my code:

```
<ion-row>
   <ion-col size="10">
     <ion-label position="floating">Contato 1* </ion-label>
   </ion-col>
   <ion-col size="2">
     <ion-img class="whatsapp"></ion-img>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

CSS :

```
.whatsapp {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url("../../assets/whatsapp.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: bottom left;
  }
```

PS: Using `ion-img [src]="assets/whatsapp" /ion-img` doesnt work!

[image]

I did what @Carlos Del Cura Pascual told me to do, and now I got this. It's almost good.

[image]

Comment: try this,  
 <ion-col size="2" position="floating">
            <ion-img class="whatsapp"></ion-img>
          </ion-col>
<ion-col size="10">
            <ion-label position="floating">Contato 1* </ion-label>
          </ion-col>

Comment: that just put the img in the beggining of the row

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox to align items inline. → https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Avoid using float or similar

```
    ion-row{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      justify-content:space-around;
      align-items:center;
      height: /* necessary to give a height to align vertically */
    }
```

Comment: I did that and now the label and input field are on the same line.